# How to call two function on Mouse over in functional components?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

```js
  
  component(props)
  
  function1(params){
  }
  
  function2(params){
  }
  render(){
  
  props.places.map((place, i) => { 
  return (
   <div onMouseOver={() => props.function1(i)}
  )
 })
 }
```

There is a small snippet of calling multiple functions into the react .
Here I want to call function1 and function2 on div mouse Over.
How to call function1 and function2 on mouseOver
This are the functional components.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give your arrow function a body and call the two functions inside of the body.

```
<div
  onMouseOver={() => {
    props.function1(i);
    props.function2(i);
  }}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

call both function

```js
  
  component(props)
  
  function1(params){
  }
  
  function2(params){
  }
  render(){
  
  props.places.map((place, i) => { 
  return (
   <div onMouseOver={() => {props.function1(i);props.function2(i)}}
  )
 })
 }
```